# How to remove in-game visual bugs on the S6?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

So after moving my apps from the S3 to the S6 on 5.0.2 a lot of my games and other apps have a visual bug constantly on the screen. But this bug is not present on the S3. Is there any way to remove it?  That circle bug can be moved around the screen too but does nothing when clicked on. Like this:[image: o]

Comment: When you hold it you should be able to move it to a trashcan. It is called a Toolbox.

Comment: What Toolbox? These bugs are not present on my S3. These are full screen games.There is no Trash. 

Comment: You should be able to switch it off in settings.

Comment: How?  What is the cause? This is in most apps that have not been updated for the S6 I gather.